# Renaming CSV file attributes in QGIS processing model

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, csv

I am trying to rename/add attribute names in CSV file that doesn´t have any attribute names (the data starts att the very first row), so I would like to add attribute names using QGIS processing.

How do I set up the algorithm Refactor fields to rename non-existing attributes?

I would like to avoid adding the names  manually, since this is a part of a larger processing model.

Comment: So now the field names are the first row values? Do you want to add them as a new row? Maybe it is possible to create an empty template table, then append all your rows to this?

Comment: The input looks like this:  

90A;20110309001448379;2;2;193651  
90A;20110309001448407;2;2;195759  

No attribute names and I can´t get the algorithm Refactor fields to rename non-existing fields. Is it possible? If not, I can open an issue on GitHub.  

I can of course add attribute names manually in a text editor:  

tabell;datum;kolumn3;kolumn4;value  
90A;20110309001448379;2;2;193651  
90A;20110309001448407;2;2;195759  

which works fine to use in Refactor fields, but since I would like to automate the whole process, adding attributes manually is less than optimal.